# XSL - matching output of call-template and other tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following problem. I am trying to transform XML file using XSL-T. I have a XSL file like this:

```
<!-- here are some imports-->
<xsl:import href="..."/>

<!-- here is template-->
<xsl:template match="...">
    <!-- here are some new tags to be added to the document -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- here is second template-->
<xsl:template match="...">
    <!-- here are some new tags and template-calls from imported xsl documents, such as: -->
    <xsl:call-template name="..."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- here is the place, where I want to create a match for output from all previous lines... -->
<!-- ... -->
```

So, the given snippet is commented to show what happens in this xsl file. I have multiple imports and many template-calls. Unfortunately, I need to add some tags to the output of all given lines and I have to do this within this file. I would prefer to use another template and match attribute, but how can I do this?

I cannot edit all imported documents. Also, I don't want to create temporary helper file. XSL version is 1.0.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please show the exact match patterns and template contents and a sample input together with the result you want.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. In general, an XSLT stylesheet operates on the XML input, not on its own output. If you want to process the result of applying a template, do the applying in a variable, then process the variable. Or have a second stylesheet process the document created by the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply a transformation to the output of another transformation, that's commonly referred to as a pipeline. There are two main techniques for implementing a pipeline in XSLT: one is to have a separate stylesheet for each transformation, and to chain them together using some external technology such as Ant, XProc, a shellscript, a Java application, or some kind of framework such as Coccoon. The other approach is a pipeline within a single stylesheet, where the typical coding pattern is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="temp1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="phase-1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="temp2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp1" mode="phase-2"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp2" mode="phase-3"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The multiple-stylesheet approach has two advantages: (a) the code is more modular and therefore more reusable, and (b) the above code doesn't actually work in XSLT 1.0 because you can't apply general processing to "result tree fragments" - you can get around this with most XSLT 1.0 processors by using the EXSLT node-set() extension function, so it becomes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp1)" mode="phase-2"/>
```

But you're on the right track looking at pipeline processing - splitting a complex transformation into a sequence of simple steps is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is just amazing.

I have already decided to use another stylesheet and add the next step of transformation to Ant build tool. This approach is much more reusable and easier to mantain and understand the logic.